# Git push is not showing files on GitHub

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have the following local repository, I am trying to push my main.py to my Github repo. On my local repository, it says the push has been successful, but then I go to my Github repo and I don't see the change.

[image: terminal output]

[image: GitHub repository]

Thanks,

Comment: You pushed `main` but you view the branch `master` on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `git status` output as well as the output after the latest `git push` shows that you were on and updated the `main` branch.

However, in the GitHub screenshot, you're viewing the `master` branch.

Most likely, you need to change the branch you're viewing on GitHub to `main`.